# Access WebApi protected with identity server 4 from vsts/tfs

Tags: asp.net-web-api, identityserver4

I want to create a vsts/tfs extension that needs to call an asp.net core web api(1.1) which is currently protected with identity server 4. All the workflows that I know need to get a bearer token from identity server in order to call the api, which I would like to avoid if possible.

Also, VSTS offers the PAT(personal access tokens) which I like very much since it's easy to use and I would like to offer something like this.

Is there a way to do something like PATs on Identity Server?

Does asp.net identity offers anything that I can use to authenticate via PATs?

Has anybody called an api protected by identityserver4 from a vsts extension? Pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Base on the IdentityServer4 document, there isn’t the token like PAT, the [protecting an API using Passwords](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/2_resource_owner_passwords.html) way also need to acquire the token.So you need to acquire the token firstly, then request the resource with that token.